# Copy/Paste doesn't snap to pixel?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm on CC 23.1.

When I copy/paste an object, it pastes correct, but the x/y positions are not snapped to pixel, even if I have `Snap to pixel` enabled.

Also on "Pixel Snapping Options" all options are enabled.

The only way is copy and "Paste on place", than move it.

Why? Its annoying and sometimes I "forget" it (so I need to adjust x/y manually, round to int).

Comment: When you paste an object, does it get "pasted" at the center of your viewport?

Comment: Illustrator pastes in the middle of the current document view. It's designed to do that. [I answered a question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/128334/89608) recently on a similar subject, with a possible hack. Not sure if it will work for you but check it out anyway.